# strptime convert string time to time

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

I try to convert a strign time like this `1:34.21` into a time.
I use this `datetime.strptime('1:34.21', '%-H:%M.%S').time()` to do the conversion but I raise this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 341, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("'%s' is a bad directive in format '%s'" %
ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%-H:%M.%S'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `'%-H:%M.%S'` to `'%H:%M.%S'`

```
from datetime import datetime
s = '1:34.21'
print(datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M.%S').time())
```

output:

```
01:34:21
```

Comment: I also try this, but sometimes with input format like in the question I have this error `ValueError: unconverted data remains: 4`. For example with a time string like `2:19.94`

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man `2:19.94` is invalid for second. what should be `94` ? Is this second ? or millisecond ?